# JxLS - Jx:Each command fails with merged cells

Tags: jxls

Each command has faced a problem when I have a merged cells below the each command's row. Please see the template and result for more details.

Template file: [template.xls](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/attachments/34/leonate/jxls/1451013686.36/34/template.xls)

Result: [result.xls](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/attachments/34/leonate/jxls/1451013686.26/34/result.xls)

Thank you so much.

**Update:** As you can see in the template I have a each command row and a total row which is merged. 
When I do render the second of the each command rows will be merged as total row. The next lines are fine.

Comment: can you please add more details, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Identicon I have added some more details. 
Hope it will be more clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've hit a [bug in JXLS](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/34/each-command-problem-with-the-merge-cells), you need to update to version 2.2.9 (or later, but at the time of writing 2.2.9 is the latest version)